# Migration problems In Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, migrate

I can not get an order "php artisan migrate" after this one is explained to me that the tables does not exist. It is the case it doesn't exist, to clarify a little, here is a semblance of what I have following the application of the command quoted above:

> [Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException] SQLSTATE [42S02]: The table
>   'eloquent.devis' does not exist (SQL: alter table Query add id int not
>   null, add id_user int not null null, null add, null add, null add,
>   null add, null add, null add, null add, table or view not found: 1146
>   The 'eloquent.devis' table does not exist

I already tried several solutions among them: composing dump-autoload and the deletion of the table users, among others. I am at the end and I would like to do the migration in order to continue my work / project of end of the year.

Comment: Please could we have this post translated into English? You're more likely to get help that way.

Comment: Okey, i have a problem with migrate function, so, when i use it "php artisan migrate or the new function php artisan migrate:refresh -seed, the console back message : the tables does'nt exist, but it's not normal" cause the table must be created following the console code.

Can some one explaine or give a solution please.??

Comment: Editors note: Original post (in French) has been run through Google Translate, and edited to remove non-essential information.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#running-migrations

try

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```